# Apache Cassandra. Specific case for an Index or a table with composite primary key

Tags: indexing, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, composite-primary-key

I have this scenario in a POC of Cassandra.

A table

```
CREATE TABLE B (B-UID UUID, 
    A-UID UUID,
    CREATED_AT timestamp ,
    JSON text,
    PARENT_B-UID UUID,
    POSTALCODE text,
    CUSTOMER_TYPE text,
    START_DATE timestamp, 
    END_DATE timestamp, 
    SOME_PRICE int, 
PRIMARY KEY (B-UID));
```

24 k rpm of write / 2 k rpm of read. For 1 A-UID I'll have 67 B-IUD in most cases.

In the life cycle of my app I'll have to Search all the B-IUD for a specific A-IUD.

My question is: Is it better create the table with a composite primary key or create an index to A-IUD? The writing performance will be affected with a composite primary key?

I already read the docs at DataStax and the example they have written there is not too good for my case, at least in my understanding!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try avoiding secondary indexes to the maximum extent

If the only query is to retrieve all B-IUD for a particular A-IUD, have a composite primary key (A-IUD, B-IUD).

If you also need to search for a particular B-IUD, have two tables

1 : Table 1 : with B-IUD as the primary key and remaining columns as is
2 : Table 2 : with a composite primary key (A-IUD, B-IUD) and remaining columns    as is

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!